# Is there a way to not including some folders when building for Apk?

Tags: flutter, flutter-build

I have to build a project using flutter that is run on web and mobiles,
Is there a way to not including some folders when building for APK because there are some files that are needed only in the web.
so if i have these folders :

- web
- mobile
- common

i need to build an APK using only mobile, common folders.
is it possible or i have to separate the project into web and mobiles?

Answer (score 0):

You can use R8 feature to achieve this.